# Unit testing internal function in react

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I want to snapshot testing (jest) just this chuck of logic of my react component. The problem is `handle1` and `handle2` aren't (of course) pure functions, they depend on other functions in `View` component, therefore I can't move the 2 lines (#4-5) in a utility function to `export`. What could be the best approach to this?

```
1    export default function View() {
2      return (
3        ...
4        {CASE1 || CASE2 && (<SidebarButton onClick={handle1}>one</SidebarButton>)}
5        {CASE2 && (<SidebarButton onClick={handle2}>two</SidebarButton>)}
6        ...
7       )
8    }
```